# CSS Navigation dropdown padding

Tags: html, css

Without adjusting my padding for my 'nav ul li' because its used for spacing out navigation links, how can i fill the full width of the dropdown links background 'nav ul li ul li' as it only seems to fill half of the background color.

```
    (HTML):

    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Num 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Num 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Num 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Num 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Num 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Num 6</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drop 2</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Num 7</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

    (css)
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cLyj9hhu/3/)

Note: Choosing not to upload CSS as i have to use the Harvard referencing system and any similarities compared with online snippets returns as a higher plagiarism percentage even if this is my own work, so i'll choose to upload more precise code on JSFiddle as its not returned from the plagiarism test.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLyj9hhu/8/)

Change your padding from `li` to `a`:

```
nav ul li  a {width:65px; display:inline-block; padding:0 30px}
```

and add the display and float proprieties to  `second-level li`:

```
nav ul li ul li { padding:0; border:none;display: list-item;float: none }
```

Answer (score -1):

well a quick way to fix this is instead of adding padding you just add the 30px on the right and left to the total width of the nav ul li which ends up being 125px

```
nav ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid #355e7f;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
}
```

Here is an updated [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLyj9hhu/7/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: why the vote down? you need to leave an explanation of why you voted my answer down. instead of just voting down without giving a reason...